# How to connect computer to tv with hdmi?

Tags: display, screen, hdmi, tv

I am trying to connect my laptop with my tv using an hdmi cable. It has worked with an vga cable, but my problem is that the screen does appear, but it freezes and nothing happens. The screen is also too big to fit the tv screen. I have checked and the sound is working perfectly fine. Any ideas on how to fix?
(Oh and the screen fits the built in laptop screen, but not the tv screen with hdmi cable)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IN display settings, choose mirrored display.

Comment: doesn't work for me.